# Channel History and Watch Later playlists after August 11th deprecations

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

Youtube has deprecated the `ontentDetails.relatedPlaylists.watchHistory` and `ontentDetails.relatedPlaylists.watchLater` API endpoints as described [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#august-11-2016).

Will there be a way to programatically access a channel's `watchHistory` and/or `watchLater` lists via other means, or will these pieces of user data be completely inaccessible via the Youtube Data API?

Thanks for any information.